# _pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK-speaker identification project

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pycharm

I am trying to build a speaker identification system using a code from GitHub but in the testing part the error "_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK " erased, I faced many errors before this one last one was "_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'".so I deleted the models file to solve the error but this new error erases can someone help me out to understand the error and solve it.

this is the code:

```
def test1():
    #source   = "testfile.wav"   
    modelpath = "models\\"       

    gmm_files = [os.path.join(modelpath,fname) for fname in 
                  os.listdir(modelpath)]

    #Load the Gaussian gender Models
    #gmm_files.seek(0)
    models = [pickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
    speakers = [fname.split("\\")[-1].split[0] for fname
                  in gmm_files]
```

the error erased in the specifically in the line:

```
 models = [pickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
```

the models file contain speakers trained models with the extension model.wav.gmm

Comment: Are you sure the files you are trying to load are pickle files?

Comment: they are speaker model after training, how I can know they are pickle files?@MatiasValdenegro

Comment: How did you save or produce these files? Also make sure that the code in the question makes sense, I cannot see where fname is coming from.

Comment: Or better, what is the full name (with extension) of the file you are trying to load?

Comment: actually I am using code from the following link https://github.com/Abhay0899193/Speaker-Recognition  the code I attached is only the part with the error form username.py file

Comment: model.wav.gmm is full name of the loaded files